# How do I modify the format of a date string? (Python/Excel)

Tags: python, excel, date, web-scraping, format

what is the best method in Python to convert a string to a given format? My problem is that I have scraped dates that have the following format: *Dec 13, 2019 6:01 am*

Ideally I want to analyse the scraped data in excel, but unfortunately Excel can not read this date format.

Do you think it is best to do that in Python or in Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definetely do this with Python using either standard library, or [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('Dec 13, 2019 6:01 am')
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 13, 6, 1)
```

Or directly to ISO format:

```
>>> dateparser.parse('Dec 13, 2019 6:01 am').isoformat()
'2019-12-13T06:01:00'
```

Another thing to look out for when working with time programmatically is time zone - it's where bugs are very likely to appear. There's a very sweet package for working with datetime data in python called [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/), I cannot stress enough how convenient it is. And it's API is completely compatible with python's standard library datetime. So you can just do `import pendulum as dt` instead of `import datetime as dt` and it will work.

It also has a great [parser](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#parsing) tool **with support for time zones**:

```
>>> import pendulum

>>> dt = pendulum.parse('1975-05-21T22:00:00')
>>> print(dt)
'1975-05-21T22:00:00+00:00

# You can pass a tz keyword to specify the timezone
>>> dt = pendulum.parse('1975-05-21T22:00:00', tz='Europe/Paris')
>>> print(dt)
'1975-05-21T22:00:00+01:00'

# Not ISO 8601 compliant but common
>>> dt = pendulum.parse('1975-05-21 22:00:00')
```

By passing the `tz` keyword argument you can parse and specify time zone at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I will also give that a go. Quite interested to work with the time zone feature.

Comment: It's not just interesting, but quite critical when parsing time sensitive data, like prices or news. Also when storing it in a database you should make sure that it's stored as time zoned data or always convert it to UTC and store as UTC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
to convert string to a datetime format.

```py
>>> utc_time = datetime.strptime("Dec 13, 2019 6:01 am", "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
>>> utc_time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %R")
'13-12-2019 06:01'
```

Comment: This approach is fragile in case date format on the scraped source will change, it's probably more pythonic to use a dedicated package. Also take a look at `datetime.datetime`'s `.isoformat()` method, instead of manually converting to string.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that has worked. But I had to add utc_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 13, 2019 6:01 am", "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p") to the line. I will give it a full go later :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use pythons inbuilt `datetime` library.

check this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html